# Unresolved dependency: firebase-database:20.2.2 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase

I would like to ask for some help for a trouble I can't solve. I want to use Firebase Realtime Database in a Spring Boot controller but when I try to import the dependency, the gradle  shows me the following error: Type Unresolved dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2. I've spend a few days reading websites, watching videos in YouTube and speaking with ChatGPT and Bard, but I didn't succeed. As far as I know, I've just need to implement the following code in the gradle:

```
// Import  for the Firebase platform  

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0
```

What I'm doing bad? Thanks everybody!

I've tried to add the dependencies on built.gradle using different versions of them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-database) it seems indeed like `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0` is not yet available.

Most recent version is `20.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

For your information the latest version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-database` according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#java)  is `20.2.2`  but you are trying to import `21.0.0`

To fix it just replace:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:21.0.0'
```

TO

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2'
```

[image]

**I just tried and all work great.**